# Could not find SpecFlow Feature .cs Files option in - VS2022

Tags: bdd, specflow, visual-studio-2022

I have visual studio 2022 in my machine and I have followed all steps and successfully installed specflow 2.4.1 through manage nuget package. but still specflow option is not displayed under Tools >> Options.Please help me to resolve this.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit)
Version 17.0.4

Frame Work - .Net 4.8

Specflow Version - 2.4.1

[image]

Comment: I am a little confused by your question. The title asks where to find the "feature.cs option", but then the body text of your question says that you cannot find SpecFlow under Tools > Options in Visual Studio. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment by Greg.. the title and the content of your question seem to be asking two different things.

However: if you want to know how to install SpecFlow tooling into Visual Studio 2022 the answer is to install via ExtensionsManager.. Extensions -> Manage Extensions. Search Online for SpecFlow